# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Transaction'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I Have been looking at this for 2 hours where is this incorrect syntax!?

Here is the line the error happens
https://i.stack.imgur.com/08tGY.png

```
public static class InvestorProcessor
    {
        public static int CreateInvestment(int id, string tickerSymbol, Sale transactionType, string companyName, int quantity, int sharePrice)
        {
            Investor data = new Investor

            {
                Id = id,
                TickerSymbol = tickerSymbol,
                TransactionType = transactionType,
                CompanyName = companyName,
                Quantity = quantity,
                SharePrice = sharePrice

            };


        string sql = @"insert into DB.Transaction (TickerSymbol, TransactionType, CompanyName, Quantity, SharePrice)
                     values (@TickerSymbol, @TransactionType, @CompanyName, @Quantity, @SharePrice);";

            return SqlDataAccess.SaveData(sql, data);

        }

        public static List<Investor> LoadInvestors()
        {
            string sql = @"select Id, TickerSymbol, TransactionType, CompanyName, Quantity, SharePrice
                           from DB.Transaction;";
            return SqlDataAccess.LoadData<Investor>(sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try escaping the table name maybe? `[DB].[Transaction]`

Comment: Your SQL is incorrect, the number of column is not matching the numbers of fields.tring sql = @"insert into DB.Transaction (TickerSymbol, TransactionType, CompanyName, Quantity, SharePrice)
                           values (EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress);";

Try in ssms

Comment: (EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress) was a miss copy paste by me its not what I had in my code I edited it. Same problem though.

Comment: values key word is now missing.

Comment: Me not highlighting the entire line when copying correctly again.. it was there though.

Answer (score 3):

`TRANSACTION` is a T-SQL [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql). If you want to have it as an object name (and generally you should avoid using reserved keywords as object names), as the docs say (my emphasis):

> Although it is syntactically possible to use SQL Server reserved keywords as identifiers and object names in Transact-SQL scripts, **you can do this only by using delimited identifiers**.

This fails, with the same error you are getting:

```
create table transaction ( id int )
```

this succeeds:

```
create table [transaction] ( id int )
```

Comment: Thank you!! Now I just get invalid object name instead of incorrect syntax!

Comment: Well are you sure there is a table `[transaction]` in your schema? And if your connection is not bound to the correct database you probably need `[databasename].[dbo].[transaction]` to select from the correct table ...

Answer (score -2):

You should try without `DB.` and check data types:

```
 string sql = @"insert into Transaction (TickerSymbol, TransactionType, CompanyName, Quantity, SharePrice)
                values (@TickerSymbol, @TransactionType, @CompanyName, @Quantity, @SharePrice);";
```

If the error persists, try to take the query into SQL Server Management Studio. You have more details there.